# Failed deserializing JSON array of strings into JAVA list of enums using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson mapper to deserialize JSON strings using its convertValue() method.

It works fine for almost everything I'm trying to do.

My problem is that I have a JSON string with list of strings:

```
{ 'game_models' : ["S", "T"] }
```

and in my Java code the mapper.convertValue tries to convert the array into Java enums as follow:

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class GameModelConverter implements AttributeConverter<GameModelType, Character> {

public enum GameModelType {
    SINGLE('S'),
    TOURNAMENT('T');

    private final char model;

    private final String collectionName;

    GameModelType(char model) {
        this.model = model;
    }


    @JsonValue
    public char value() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

This is my converting method:

```
public void convert(GameModelType... game_models) {
    mapper.convertValue(game_models, GameModelType.class);
}
```

Exception:

```
GameModelConverter$GameModelType out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

**EDIT:**
Stack trace:

```
2014-11-14 16:41:02,707 ERROR [JsonUniChannel] - Unhandled exception in     
Message=RxMessage[{"action":"games_inventory","session_id":"096768b6-c2ad-4111-8b9f-    
862fbe15684d","game_models":["T","S"]}]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not deserialize instance of    
com.sbg.helper.GameModelConverter$GameModelType out of START_OBJECT   
token at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2615) ~[jackson- 
databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2] 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542) ~ 
[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.luckyrhino.core.common.commands.JsonUniChannel.buildParams(JsonUniChannel.java:135)  
[core-common-1.0.jar:na] 
at com.luckyrhino.core.common.commands.JsonUniChannel.call(JsonUniChannel.java:76) [core-common-1.0.jar:na] 
at com.luckyrhino.core.common.commands.JsonUniChannel.call(JsonUniChannel.java:24) [core-common-1.0.jar:na] at rx.Observable$25.onNext(Observable.java:6656) [rxjava-core-0.20.0- RC2.jar:na]
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:105) [rxjava-core-0.20.0-RC2.jar:na] 
at io.vertx.rxcore.java.impl.SingleSubscriptionHandler.fireNext(SingleSubscriptionHandler.java:107) [mod-rxvertx-1.0.0-beta4.jar:na]
at io.vertx.rxcore.java.eventbus.RxEventBus$ReceiveHandler.handle(RxEventBus.java:77) [mod-rxvertx-1.0.0-beta4.jar:na]
at io.vertx.rxcore.java.eventbus.RxEventBus$ReceiveHandler.handle(RxEventBus.java:75) [mod-rxvertx-1.0.0-beta4.jar:na]
at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.DefaultEventBus$11.run(DefaultEventBus.java:951) [vertx-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:175) [vertx-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
at   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370) [netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353) [netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) [netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25] Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.luckyrhino.sbg.shareddata.helper.GameModelConverter$GameModelType out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:569) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:114) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:20) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.handleNonArray(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:232) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:135) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2610) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please provide more context for your code. It looks like that error is occurring in deserialization, but I don't see where that's happening. Also, print the entire stack trace; that's only a small fragment of the message.

Comment: Updated with stack trace - Thank you.

Comment: Single quotes are not valid JSON. Try running the JSON through an online validator.

Comment: I took it from the javascript so it looks like that, but when it's transferred to java server handling it appears with double quote.

Comment: I would suggest using a later version of Jackson: 2.4.3 is the latest version, and should be compatible with 2.2 that you are using currently. But if nothing else, at least upgrade to `2.2.4`, the last patch release for 2.2 branch.

Comment: I updated to 2.4.3 but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Trying again to see if someone has the answer....